# Grails - How to change project's Grails version in Spring Tool Suite 3.5.1

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

In Spring Tool Suite 3.5.1.Release , how do I set a project-specific Grails version?

I have multiple versions of Grails configured in STS.

Older versions of STS had a section called Grails in the "Properties for *project*" window where a particular version of Grails could be selected.

After upgrading to 3.5.1.Release I no longer see this option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since GGTS version 3.5.0 the Grails version GGTS uses now always follows the application.properties file in your project. So just change the grails version number in that file.

You may need to do some other things to actually upgrade your project to work with that newer version of Grails of course.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Wasn't sure if that was the "right way" since that setting used to be in the GUI.

Comment: Yes, going forward this is how it will work. As a bit of background on the why... Grails 2.4 no longer supports the 'upgrade' command which was part of the old workflow supported by the GUI. That's the main reason we had to change it. Also... a lot of problems happen because the tooling and the grails project don't agree on which grails version is supposed to be used. Now that is no longer possible which makes a lot of problems go away :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please go through following step for customize your grails version in GGTS.

1) Go to Window toolbar.

2) Select Preferences.

3) Type grails on textbox and Search

you can see **grails installations:** where you can add and remove your different grails version. if you need to add grails version please add path of your grails version and select check box for that grails version. after adding and removing grails version you must click on **OK** button